# Get custom taxonomy terms that contain posts that have another taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, multi-taxonomy-query

I have two taxonomies for my `property` post type:
`property-style` which has terms for different home styles like "Country" and "Modern", and
`property-tag` which has terms for amenities such as "Swimming Pool" and "Garage".

On the main page I list all of the `property-style` terms with the post count:

- Classic [1 Post]
- Country [0 Posts]
- Modern [4 Posts]
- Rustic [3 Posts]

I get these terms by using:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'property-style',
    'hide_empty'    => false,
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'asc',
) );
```

On the main page is also a dropdown containing all the `property-tag` terms, so they can filter the `property-style` terms, showing only terms that include posts with the selected `property-tag` term.

So let's say the `property-tag` dropdown has `Swimming Pool` selected, and there's only 1 property with a Swimming Pool and it has the `property-style` of "Modern". So now the main page should show:

- Classic [0 Posts]
- Country [0 Posts]
- Modern [1 Post]
- Rustic [0 Posts]

How can I get all the `property-style` terms, but filtered by `property-tag = Swimming Pool`?

Comment: What you're describing is called "faceted" search. Implementing it yourself is likely to be quite complicated and the result is likely to be very slow, as the WordPress database is not well optimised for it. If you search for that term "Faceted search" you might find some existing solutions, like Facet WP or ElasticPress. These generally require exporting the data into a separate database format that is better optimised for this type of query.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!